# Hang small pots on 4"x4" wood post?

Tags: houseplants, containers, outdoor

I have a small terrace and the fence is built with several 4"x4" posts.

I also have many 6.5”/2.5qt plastic pots with different cacti.

Is there a quick and inexpensive do-it-yourself to hang these pots on the 4"x4" wooden posts?

Answer (score 1):

Drill holes through the ends of 16-24" boards.

Screw the center of the boards to the posts. Board horizontal.

Make macrame (or more generally string)  plant hangers if your pots are not of the "hanging" type already. Very DIY of the old skool.

Assemble in the obvious way.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

1. Cut a piece of aluminum flashing so that it's just large enough to cover the top of each 4x4. This will keep the post from rotting from the top down.
2. Cut 1" x 4" strips of wood; best if you use cedar to prevent the
   strips from rotting. FUrring strips work well, but are likely to rot quickly unless treated.
3. Place the flashing on top of the post, then nail two of the strips
   on either side of the 4x4 (this leaves the center of the post
   open for drainage).
4. Drill a hole in the bottom of a plastic pot (with a center drainage hole) so that you can screw the pot to one of the wooden strips.
5. Screw the plastic pot  into the strip, fill with potting mix, and plant.